# Navigating to a different activity using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to navigate from one activity to another using the navigation controller. I have not been able to find a single example that illustrates how to accomplish this. The Android docs indicate to use one of these for navigating:

Kotlin

```
* Fragment.findNavController()
* View.findNavController()
* Activity.findNavController(viewId: Int)
```

Java

```
* NavHostFragment.findNavController(Fragment)
* Navigation.findNavController(Activity, @IdRes int viewId)
* Navigation.findNavController(View)
```

I am using Kotlin. For whatever strange reason, Google chose to create separate methods for Kotlin and Java.

Comment: The Kotlin ones are extension functions meant to be a nicer alternative to the corresponding Java static methods.  
So, if you are inside a fragment, instead of calling `NavHostFragment.findNavController(this)` you can just call `findNavController()`.

Answer (score 2):

Definitivelly you need to use:

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_loginFragment_to_mainActivity)
```

In My case I have to use:

```
val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
val btnUbicacion = root.findViewById<View>(R.id.btn_ubicacion) as Button
btnUbicacion.setOnClickListener{
  activity!!.findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.nav_gallery)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First add the second activity as a destination in navigation. Give this transactionAction a name . and then in code use .

```
Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.myTransaction);
```

Comment: When I go to add the second activity as a destination, it is not listed from the items that I can choose from.

Comment: what is view? for this usage

Comment: It can be the activity in which you are  or the button you clicked

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that in the Navigation Editor that you must manually enter in the destination of the activity that you wish to navigate to. You must do this in the text view and not in the designer view. This appears to be a bug or a seriously lacking feature in the Navigation Editor. It really should list all of the activities in your app, which it currently does not. In my app, I want to navigate from the Login activity to the main activity. This is done as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/nav_graph_login"
            app:startDestination="@id/loginFragment">

    <fragment android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
              android:name="com.linkedintools.ui.login.LoginFragment"
              android:label="login_fragment"
              tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login">
        <action android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_mainActivity" app:destination="@id/mainActivity"/>
    </fragment>

    <activity android:id="@+id/mainActivity" 
              android:name="com.linkedintools.ui.main.MainActivity"
              android:label="mainActivity"/>
</navigation>
```

I then navigate using this:

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_loginFragment_to_mainActivity)
```

Comment: During development of this navigation system they decided to use fragment as the base model instead of activity. May be this is the reason we cant see activity in the navigation.xml